# Show sidebar only if filter is active in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a sidebar that should be visible only if filter is active. How could I check this?

Basicly, I should add something to `:if` condition:

```
sidebar I18n.t("active_admin.charts.revenue.title"), :if => ??? do
  # sidebar content goes here
end
```

What should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `params['q']`, which is a array of checked (if any) options in filter (from what I understand).
I assume (though I did not test it) you can check if `params['q']` is `blank`, and if it is, you don't show sidebar, otherwise you do:

```
sidebar I18n.t("active_admin.charts.revenue.title"), unless params['q'].blank? do
end
```